# What was the name of this novel series with a ship called the Sea Witch?

Tags: story-identification, books

A fantasy series wherein the main character is a woman who discovers and has to explore her abilities. In one of the earlier books she meets a guy who is more than he seems and who has a father he is running from. He and his father work for some government agency. They become a couple. She meets and becomes friends with a red haired witch whose husband the main character has known previously.  They have a very rambunctious son who also has abilities. There's a ship named the Sea Witch in one of the later novels. There is also a cop who the main character consults with and I almost recall her being a PI. The main character defeats the bad guys

> and loses her leg in the final battle.

Comment: Could you [edit] to expand on what these abilities are?

Comment: I'm not sure how any of the things you've said are spoilers are spoilers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Greywalker**

A little googling finds the [*Greywalker* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41939-greywalker) by Kat Richardson. [Volume 7](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12260585-seawitch) is called *Seawitch*.

The back cover text fits your description:

> Harper Blaine was your average small-time PI until she died—for two minutes. Now Harper is a Greywalker, treading the thin line between the living world and the paranormal realm. And she’s discovering that her new abilities are landing her all sorts of “strange” cases.
> A quarter-century ago, the Seawitch cruised away from her dock and disappeared with everyone on board. Now, the boat has mysteriously returned to her old berth in Seattle and the insurance company has hired Harper to find out what happened.
> But Harper is not the only one investigating. Seattle Police Detective Rey Solis is a good cop, albeit one who isn’t comfortable with the creepy cases that always seem to end up in Harper’s lap. As they explore the abandoned vessel, Harper and Solis discover a cabin containing symbols drawn in human blood, revealing the ghost ship’s grave history.

As Solis focuses on the possible murder of a passenger’s wife, Harper’s investigation leads her to a powerful being who may be responsible for the disappearance of the Seawitch’s passengers and crew. And while their searches lead Harper and Solis in different directions, they will need to put aside their differences to solve a deadly mystery twenty-five years in the making.

[image]

Search terms: "urban fantasy"  son running from father government agency ship "sea witch"

Comment: Yes! The red haired witch is *Mara Danziger*, her husband is *Ben* and their son is *Brian*.

Comment: @JohnRennie: If you accept the answer, please mark it as correct.  :-)

Comment: I'm not the OP! I was just commenting to confirm your id. I have the book so I was able to check and confirm the details in the question. Also at the end of the book *Seawitch* Harper's left leg is badly hurt and there is speculation that it might need to be amputated, but at the end of the book the leg hasn't (yet) been lost.

Comment: Thanks! This is it!